# Blueimp File Upload Progress returns 100% of total.

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

The data.loaded returned always returns the full amount of the data.total

I have tested this with almost every configuration. The ONLY way it will work is with chunked data.

The demo versions available are also showing this issue. Upload any file with their test files and it will immediately display 100%, the progress bar will fill.

Has something changed somewhere for this to be the case as it used to work ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was being caused by Fiddler. The hooks were being sourced and preventing a return path to the browser.

Solution - turn off Fiddler.

Embarrassing.